# MariaDB/MySQL tmp tables are eating up whole disk space

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We've got one database sized about 4GB and one over-complicated view (with GROUP_BY, GROUP_CONCAT, etc), that we cannot change currently.

Sometimes MariaDB 10 is creating on disk temporary files (in /tmp), when we are querying that view. Files are sized more than 40GB - it seems like endless. 
I understand why these files are created, but I cannot understand why these files are bigger than all data that we have.

Is it possible that recursive joins are cause of that? 
Why it happens not every time, but only sometimes? (cache size, buffers ?)

There is any way to prevent such situation by configuration?
How big this kind of tables could grow?

Comment: Or missing index?  Or "inflate-deflate" caused by `JOIN...GROUP BY`?  Let's see one of the queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Yes, we also got missing indexes :), when we added them whole operation slowed down to unacceptable time range . I'm not sure showing whole query without whole database could be useful in that case. It got everything what's bad. What do you mean by inflate-deflate in that case?

Comment: What index did you add that slowed things down?

Comment: Just adding indexes in some fields accelerates query, but  on particular fields it's slowing query down. Maybe because view query is dependant on another view query and because of that it creates temporary tables in memory with indexes etc...

Comment: Sounds like anther case for avoiding `VIEWs`.

Comment: What version are you using?  There _may_ have been improvements in recent versions.

Comment: @RickJames - 10.1, so pretty recent.

Answer (score 0):

I've probably found a reason by digging up:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

It's a old post with some fresh comments with stories shared by users.
Massimiliano Alessandri pointed there that using VIEW in MySQL for them was causing that generated resultset was written to disk then searched WITHOUT indexes with GBytes of data. It seems like our problem also. 
Only solution for this is not using VIEWS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the binary logs are activated. You could try to purge them with this SQL command:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html